# NSArray of UITextFields, how can i find a specific one?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i loaded up an array with UITextFields, they are all created dynamically (and locally) and i need to keep reference to them for a later point.

my text fields are name, textField01, textField02, etc.

i want to pull out textField02 out and change the data. how can i search through my array of them get it out? i tried "isEqualToString" and failed. i can't use the .tag cause i'm using that for something else. i can't compare to the .text value cause i don't know what it will be (entered by user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `NSDictionary` here. Add each text field with a named key that you'll use for retrieval later.

Comment: i'm creating the text field (it is not an instance variable), the user will enter the data and when he hits save, i need to retrieve that data from the text field. so i need to keep that text field object.

Comment: `NSDictionary` will retain references to the objects you store in it until it is released. What's the problem?

Comment: oh, do you mean have the value would be text field?

Comment: Yes, just keep an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` around and add your text fields as they are created. `[someMutableDictionary setObject:newlyCreatedTextField forKey:@"FirstTextFieldKey"];`

Answer (score 2):

If you are naming them sequentially why not just add them to an `NSMutableArray`

Then you can get at them by index.

```
NSMutableArray *textFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
UITextField *textField = nil;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    [textFields addObject:textField];
    [textField release]; textField = nil;
}
```

Later on

```
UITextField *myTextField = [textFields objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: i thought about doing this, but i wasn't sure if that would be the safest way to go. and if i ever change the amount of text fields, i'd have to redo the retrieval code also. if i search, i won't have too.